# Do I need to recompile TensorFlow to change versions of android SDK and NDK?

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk, android-sdk-2.3

When I compile tensorflow (current version from `master`) on linux, I go through the prompts to select versions of the Android NDK and SDK. The build goes fine. But, my questions are...

1. If I want to switch to a different version of NDK and/or SDK, do I need to do `bazel clean` and recompile tensorflow from scratch?
2. I have seen some 3rd-party tutorials such as [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/wiki/Deploy-your-TensorFlow-Lite-Model-in-Android), which say that in the WORKSPACE file, you should uncomment something that looks like this:

```
#android_ndk_repository(
#    name="androidndk",
#    path="<PATH_TO_NDK>",
#    api_level=14)
```

However, I don't see anything like this in the WORKSPACE that's currently at the top-level directory of tensorflow's master branch. If I want to manually edit the above code, where would I find it?

Based on [this readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/guide/android.md), I think the auto-generated `.tf_configure.bazelrc` is possibly relevant?

3. I use cmake but I am totally new to bazel (tensorflow's build system), and I don't yet really understand the basic principles and patterns of bazel. What's the eqivalent to CMakeLists.txt in Bazel? That is, where do the *answers* to all the questions that you get asked in the configure script get written down?